# How does one test if a backup of an `.mdb` file is good in an automated manner?

Tags: vba, ms-access-2003, legacy, legacy-database

I make a copy of an `.mdb` database (and it's other partition) every night, and test it by opening it up to see if it works.

**By** "make a copy" **I mean:**

1. I kick all the users out of the database who are connected via RDP (not automated...)
2. Rename both backend files...and then proceed to make a copy of the files.  (automated...)

**And by** "see if it works" **I mean:**

1. Relink a frontend file (`.mde`) to both files (this is automated)
2. Open it (and it's other partition) with a frontend (`.mde`) and workgroup security file (`.mdw`) on my local machine to see if it works. (this is not automated, and the part I am focusing on here...)

There are only two tables in the other partition, so I run the part of the frontend file I know uses that partition to test if the backup is going to work.

Would connecting to the backup of the files and doing a query on some table in both partitions be enough to prove that the backup is good without actually looking at it with human eyes?

I have also automated the process of compacting the live database, but I don't feel safe automating this part until I have verified that the backups indeed work.

Also before I get any posts along the lines of "Why are you still using access?", let me just state that I don't get to make those decisions and this database was here a long time before I got here.

*(Please Note: if you feel I have posted this on SO in error please feel free to migrate to the [DBA SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) or to [Serverfault](http://www.serverfault.com/))*

Comment: SQL-Server has this nice feature that logs to a file when you do a backup, and then you can check it to see if anything went wrong.  Access, being file-based has no such niceties that I am aware of.  But I know that if someone writes to the database file while you're copying it, that generally kills your copy of the backup, which is why I rename it.

Comment: (Could probably change the security on it too...but it's always good to test your backups)

Comment: Just a thought, no research File Compare http://www.computerhope.com/fchlp.htm